# how to group by sql data in a sub-query to show evolution

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, subquery

I have my sqlite database which contains urls and the number of times it has been visited per week. it's stored this way :

```
uid, url, date, nb_visits,...
```

I would like to get every single URL with the evolution of the number of visits grouped by date.
something that could looks like :

```
 "my_url_1","45,54,76,36,78"
```

here my assumption is that there are 5 dates stored into the db, don't need the dates, just want them to be ordered from old to recent
I tried something like this, but don't accept 2 field in the second select

```
select url, visits,
(select sum(visits) from data d2 where d2.url=d1.url group by date) as evol
from data d1
where date = (select max(date) from data);
```

This query isn't working just wanted to share what i'm trying to do
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the result of `GROUP_CONCAT()` for each url.
The problem with the aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()` is that it does not support an `ORDER BY` clause, which you need to sort the visits by date, so the result that you would get is not guaranteed to be correct.

In SQLite there is also a `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function which supports an `ORDER BY` clause and can be used to return the result that you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url,
       GROUP_CONCAT(visits) OVER (
         PARTITION BY url 
         ORDER BY date
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
       ) visits
FROM data
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e6c8cd7d403355de9203fbb859528125).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `group_concat()`?

```
select url, group_concat(visits)
from (select d.*
      from data d
      order by url, date
     ) d
group by url;
```

Note:  SQLite doesn't support an `order by` as part of the `group_concat()` syntax.  In theory, sorting in the subquery should have the desired effect of ordering the dates.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff the group by doesn't look to work, it gives me more values than existing in the databse (more dates), and it returns only 1 result

Comment: @DanyM . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?  This returns one row per URL, and all the dates associated with the URL, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: here is a fiddle with a very simple data https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vc47ihLSbK1mpct7af7tEk/0#&togetherjs=T6kqKQ1LIV

Comment: @DanyM . . . The results look correct to me.  I think you need to clarify your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: yes it doesn't work on my database. let me prepare a set of data. would you accept a private chat?